# Delta cycle simulation, What happens when two inputs in sensitivity list changes at same time and logic is conditioned with both of these inputs

Tags: verilog

I have a piece of code as :

```
always_ff @(posedge X or posedge ~Y)              
        begin                                                
         if (~Y)  Z <= '0;                                  
         else      Z <=  1'b1;                                  
        end
```

Both X and Y are rising at same time (~Y is falling).
I was assuming Z to go 1, but instead Z was 0 in my simulations..

Because when we have classic code of async RST Flop :

```
always_ff @(posedge rst)              
        begin                                                
         if (rst)  Z <= '0;                                  
         else      Z <=  1'b1;                                  
        end
```

We see Z going 0 as soon as rst goes 1.

(What i think is happening : As ~Y is falling, its not triggering the simulation of this block of code. so its still having previous value 0 in delta cycle simulation)

What is happening here, can somebody explain in detail.

Comment: Your example of a "classic" async reset flop is not a flop at all. There's no clock there.

Comment: @Kavin, thanks for pointing out, That is a miss from my side and I am not able to edit the question, you can read it as : ` always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge rst)

Answer (score 1):

In event-driven simulation such as Verilog, there is no such thing as "Changing at the same time" One must come before the other and sometimes that order is undefined.

Your problem is most likely want only one `posedge` in the sensitivity list, and that is required by synthesis tool.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for answering quickly, 
For synthesis : this will get synthesized as a Asynchronous reset flop with ~Y as as reset and X as clock. And in silicon if both of these change at same time, that will put this flop in metastable state. 
But according to above comment of yours, in simulation value of Z will be unpredictable/Random? 
sometimes it may come as 0 and sometimes it may come as 1.

Comment: If X and Y have predictable change ordering, then Z is predictable. If that is not the case, then Z is unpredictable. Unpredictable is not the same as being random.

Comment: In hardware you will also have a race condition/timing error. If an asynchronous reset register is to work reliably, the reset and clock must **not** change at the same time. (Just like you have a race condition if the D input and clock change at the same time)